# Changing fields order in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, vector, fields-attributes, order

I have to draw several stuff and input the data, all the layers have the same data fields but some require 2\5 attributes to be filled.

Is there a way to change the order of those fields to be on top so I get to input them easier without changing the order of the field themselves?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open the [Fields](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#fields-properties) tab from the [Layer properties](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#the-vector-properties-dialog). From there, select the [Drag and drop designer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#the-drag-and-drop-designer) option and drag to the right the fields you want to edit. You can also change the field order.

You can then edit a feature and choose to display the fields in `form view`. Only the fields you selected in the previous step will be shown.

[image: Layer property, field tab]

[image: Restrict fields to be edited]

Comment: Is it possible to do this programmatically via PyQgis API?

Comment: Ok, found https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsEditFormConfig.html which responsible for that.

Comment: There is no "drag and drop" option here. Is this changed in newer versions?

Comment: @DanielMöller It's still there (but I can't guess which version you are using and if there is a bug or not in a very specific release)

Comment: I'm using 3.28.5-Firenze and couldn't find it at all. I resorted to the "Refactor fields" answer.

Comment: in 3.28 and above the "Drag and Drop designer" is part of "Layer Properties / Attribute Forms" - according to the interface the form layout can be arranged ... unfortunately dragging the fields order into a way I would like to have doesn't change anything in my forms

Answer (score 18):

Open the attribute table. Right-click the column headings in the attribute table. Select "Organize columns" in the drop-down menu.

Then, just drag the heading to the position you want it to be in (See the image of the "organize table columns" box below).

Click <kbd>OK</kbd>. Headings should have rearranged the way you want them to be arranged in the attribute table.

[image]

Comment: This does not save the changed order in the original files.

Answer (score 10):

If I understand your question, you may use the ["Refactor fields"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) algorithm from the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>): it allows manipulating the order of your fields stored in the Attribute Table.

> Allows editing the structure of the attribute table of a vector layer.
>
> Fields can be modified in their type and name, using a fields mapping.
>
> The original layer is not modified. A new layer is generated, which
> contains a modified attribute table, according to the provided fields
> mapping.

Comment: it's exactly what i was looking for except that it creates a new layer with the new attributes order .. is there a way to do the same with the layer itself without creating a new one?

Comment: @AbdullahAlaa, maybe not with common tools. Can't you overwrite the original layer? Maybe your task could be accomplished using some PyQGIS code.

Answer (score 5):

#### This solution only changes the order of columns in the attribute table, and not in the original file.

This PyQGIS solution utilizes the [`setColumns()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsAttributeTableConfig.html#a8a018be39a06e7caa2202adf868daae7) and [`setAttributeTableConfig()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ab91616c2e2e296fa97a3ab8bc0a36f7d) methods.

Let's assume there is a layer called *'gis_osm_buildings'*, see the image below.

[image: input]

To get the original order of fields:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print([layer.attributeDisplayName(index) for index in layer.attributeList()])
```

that gives:

```
['osm_id', 'lastchange', 'code', 'fclass', 'geomtype', 'name', 'type', 'height', 'levels']
```

To set a new order of fields one can achieve with the following function:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

def setting_new_columns_order(layer_name: str, new_order: list) -> None:
    """
    Changes order of all columns in the layer
    Parameters:
    ==========
    :param layer_name: name of the layer
    :param new_order: a list with a new order of columns
    """

    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    layer_attr_table_config = layer.attributeTableConfig()
    columns_config = layer_attr_table_config.columns()

    columns_new_order_dict = {column : new_order.index(column.name) for column in columns_config if
                              column.type == 0 and column.name in new_order}
    columns_new_order_list = sorted(columns_new_order_dict, key=columns_new_order_dict.get, reverse=False)

    layer_attr_table_config.setColumns(columns_new_order_list)
    layer.setAttributeTableConfig(layer_attr_table_config)

    return

setting_new_columns_order('gis_osm_buildings', ['name', 'type', 'osm_id', 'code', 'fclass', 'height', 'levels', 'lastchange', 'geomtype'])
```

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html)

Comment: How can this be done without loading the source into the layer?

Comment: You mean with PyQGIS or another Python package ?

Comment: in QGIS with python

Comment: Possible, you just need to read your vector layer like described here: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the ["Table manager"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tablemanager/) plugin only available on QGIS 2.18 and > which only lets you edit the vector file without creating a new one.