# Changing column order with Table Manager Plugin in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, attribute-table, fields-attributes

There was a [Table Manager](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tablemanager/) Plugin in earlier QGIS versions I can't see it for QGIS 3 anymore.

Is there a way to achieve this in QGIS 3.6?

Comment: If you are satisfied with either answer, please check the "accept" button, it would be helpful for those who dedicated their time to answer :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, you can use the ["Refactor fields"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) tool from the Toolbox:

[image: Refactor fields]

Answer (score 8):

See my answer here: [QGIS changing the attribute input fields order](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240258/qgis-changing-the-attribute-input-fields-order/348160#348160)

Open the attribute table. Right click the column headings in the attribute table. Select "Organize columns" in drop down menu. Then, just drag the heading to the position you want it to be in (See image of the "organize table columns" box below). Click OK. Headings should have rearranged the way you want it to be arranged in the attribute table.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do the same in python ?

Comment: @SYG Yes, several ways. Check geopandas library for example

Comment: Does this only change the order within the current QGIS project? Or does it actually edit the order in the shapefile?