# Reording fields in Identify Results panel

Tags: qgis

What can be done to modify the fields order in the `Identify Result` panel, idealy without re-creating a new layer?

Modifying the table field order or the UI field order, as described in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240258/qgis-changing-the-attribute-input-fields-order), does not affect the  `Identify Result` panel.

Having a layer with fields `a`, `b` and `c`, I would like to show `c`,`b`,`a` (or any other custom order). I am currently using QGIS 3.4.15 LTR.

[image]

Comment: Virtual layer with `SELECT c, b, a, geometry FROM "New scratch layer" ?

Comment: :-) yes, a virtual layer or a view would do. I was hopping for a solution in the same layer (similar to the table field ordering)

Comment: Processing > Refactor fields ?

Comment: Thanks, this looks like another good solution that creates a new layer (although it the tool refused to work and threw an error, but it's a different topic)

Comment: It may be necessary to assign new identities to the fields in the index, and for that it may be necessary to create new fields with the same attributes and delete the previous ones. I don't think it's a reasonable solution but at least one possible.