# Moving widgets fields to the top in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, widget, order

I would like to change the order of my widgets in the attribute form section.

[image]

But after changing the order of columns in the data attribute table, they remain still in the same order in the "Available Widgets" section. Thereby, their order cannot be changed when exporting the given layer with the QGIS2web plugin.

[image]

Both links:

- https://www.qgistutorials.com/sl/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzFtc8HZvyk&ab_channel=GISCoordinated

As well as changing the "Autogenerate" to "drag & drop designer"
don't solve this problem, showing how to fill them up, on the contrary.

Is there any way to change the order of fields in the "Available widgets" section?

Comment: Some information can be also found here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240258/changing-fields-order-in-qgis

Comment: Yes I see, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QGIS2web uses `fields()` method of `QgsVectorLayer` class to get the fields, and that method *uses fields order of the data provider*. I mean, it retrieves the fields as in the data source. Therefore, changing the field order in QGIS has no effect.

One solution I can recommend to you is to use ["Refactor Fields"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) tool. Using this tool, you can create a new layer with altered field order.

[image]

*Before (in QGIS2web):*

[image]

*After:*

[image]